# conditional joining in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Conditional joining statement : -

**High level Description  :-** 
Join table based on two columns if combination is not present then join on one table -

**Detailed Table -**

```
create table tab1
(tab1_col1 number not null,
tab1_col2 number null,
tab1_col3 varchar(10));
```

**Lookup Table**

```
create table lkp1
(lkp_col1 number not null,
lkp_col2 number not null,
lkp_col3 number not null,
lkp_col4 varchar(10));
```

**Insert Statement - 
tab1**

```
insert into tab1 values (10,101,'A');
insert into tab1 values (12,101,'B');
insert into tab1 values (11,102,'C');
insert into tab1 values (13,103,'B');
insert into tab1 values (14,104,'C');
insert into tab1 values (15,108,'A');
insert into tab1 values (16,102,'D');
```

**Lookup Table
lkp1**

```
insert into lkp1 values (10,101,50,'PICK');
insert into lkp1 values (10,101,50,'PICK');
insert into lkp1 values (11,102,100,'SKIP');
insert into lkp1 values (11,110,50,'PICK');
insert into lkp1 values (13,103,40,'PICK');
insert into lkp1 values (13,103,60,'PICK');
insert into lkp1 values (14,199,100,'PICK');
insert into lkp1 values (15,115,80,'PICK');
insert into lkp1 values (15,115,20,'PICK');
```

**Requirement was** - 
Join table based on tab1_col1=lkp_col1 
and 
tab1_col2=lkp_col2
Filter out lookup table data lkp_col4=SKIP
If record not present in lookup table for then give default value(99.99).
(All records from tab1 table should be selected).

I built this query and it was working fine.

```
SELECT tab1_col1, tab1_col2, NVL (lkp_col3, '99.99') "LKP_COL3"
  FROM tab1,
       (SELECT *
          FROM lkp1
         WHERE lkp_col4 = 'PICK') lkp
 WHERE tab1_col1 = lkp_col1(+) AND tab1_col2 = lkp_col2(+)
```

**Now requirement changed** 
First check if 
tab1_col1=lkp_col1 
and 
tab1_col2=lkp_col2
If lookup table is not having data for this combination 
then check again with 
tab1_col1=lkp_col1 
If this is not also available then give dafault value.

Database - Oracle 10g

**What I have tried so far**

After lot of trail and error I m able to get the output. However, is there a better or simple way to use this ?

```
SELECT tab1_col1, tab1_col2, LKP_COL3
  FROM tab1,
       (SELECT *
          FROM lkp1
         WHERE lkp_col4 = 'PICK') lkp
 WHERE tab1_col1 = lkp_col1 AND tab1_col2 = lkp_col2
 union all
 SELECT tab1_col1, tab1_col2, LKP_COL3
  FROM tab1,
       (SELECT *
          FROM lkp1
         WHERE lkp_col4 = 'PICK') lkp
 WHERE tab1_col1 = lkp_col1(+)
 AND  
 LKP_COL1|| '-' || LKP_COL2 not in( SELECT tab1_col1|| '-' || tab1_col2
  FROM tab1, lkp1 lkp
 WHERE tab1_col1 = lkp_col1 AND tab1_col2 = lkp_col2)
 order by 1
```

Comment: In case 2-fields-lookup-record doesn't exist is it guaranteed that the only 1-field-lookup-record exists?

Comment: No, that is valid scenarios. if 1-feild lookup doesnt exists then need to give default value. (need all data from tab1 to be selected)

Comment: And can be found several 1-field lookups? Now I see too many 2-field lookups, could you say if all of them are needed as a result set?

Comment: yes all of them need as a result set

Comment: @Vladimir Chervanev : I have put up query now which is giving me result what is required. Is the a better way to write this ?

Comment: The query you use gives the same output as my query (below) except that mine has no duplicates. Mine also has a better explain plan. have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

The following result:

```
| TAB1_COL1 | TAB1_COL2 | LKP_COL3 |
|-----------|-----------|----------|
|        10 |       101 |       50 |
|        11 |       102 |       50 |
|        12 |       101 |    99.99 |
|        13 |       103 |       40 |
|        13 |       103 |       60 |
|        14 |       104 |      100 |
|        15 |       108 |       20 |
|        15 |       108 |       80 |
|        16 |       102 |    99.99 |
```

was produced by this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      tab1.tab1_col1
    , tab1.tab1_col2
    , COALESCE(lkp1.lkp_col3, lkp2.lkp_col3, 99.99) "LKP_COL3"
FROM tab1
      LEFT JOIN lkp1
                  ON tab1.tab1_col1 = lkp1.lkp_col1
                        AND tab1.tab1_col2 = lkp1.lkp_col2
                        AND lkp1.lkp_col4 = 'PICK'
      LEFT JOIN lkp1 lkp2
                  ON tab1.tab1_col1 = lkp2.lkp_col1
                        AND lkp2.lkp_col4 = 'PICK'
ORDER BY
      tab1.tab1_col1
    , tab1.tab1_col2
;
```

DISTINCT was added because the second left (outer) join produces unwanted repetition in the output.

refer to this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fc86e/18)

Comment: THanks. Tab1 having tab1_col2=10,tab1_col2-101 has two rows in lookup table and I need both having value 50. (Its percentage column)

Comment: I have edited my question, I have mentioned query there now which is giving me desireed output but its taking lot of time when I m implemenating in my main query. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: The query you use gives the same output as my query (above) except that mine has no duplicates. Mine also has a better explain plan. have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried after removing distinct but in that case, wherever there is col1 and co2 match its giving me 2 set of rows. How to remove that one? e,g. (col1=10, col2=101 is giving me 4 rows instead of 2)

Comment: why did you remove distinct? I mentioned that my approach produces unwanted repitition, distinct was added for a reason.